How to create a Stop Market order in Binance Futures API
I am trying to use the Binance API to create a stop market order like its done in the Web Application but I keep running into problems. The few times the code goes through, it only creates the first Stop Market order and skips the other two. Any help on this?
I have a class to help with Binance Future Orders:
from binance.client import Client
from binance.enums import *
from binance.exceptions import BinanceAPIException, BinanceOrderException
from helpers import custom_exceptions


class BinanceApi:
    def __init__(self, key: str, secret: str) -> None:
        """
        Class to incorporate and handle the Binance Futures API using the python-binance library.
        @param key: API Key
        @param secret: API Secret
        """
        try:
            self.client = Client(api_key=key, api_secret=secret)
        except (BinanceAPIException, BinanceOrderException) as e:
            raise custom_exceptions.BinanceClientErrorException(str(e))

    def stop_market_order(self, symbol: str, side: str, quantity: float, stop_price: float, reduce_only: bool = False) -> dict:
        """
        Method to create a stop market order.
        @param symbol: The trading pair symbol (e.g., 'BTCUSDT').
        @param side: BUY or SELL.
        @param quantity: The quantity to trade.
        @param stop_price: The price that triggers the market order.
        @param reduce_only: If True, order will only reduce the position size.
        @return: Response from Binance API as a dictionary.
        """
        try:
            response = self.client.futures_create_order(
                symbol=symbol,
                side=side,
                quantity=quantity,
                reduceOnly=reduce_only,
                type=FUTURE_ORDER_TYPE_STOP_MARKET,
                stopPrice=stop_price,
                priceProtect=True
            )
            return response
        except (BinanceAPIException, BinanceOrderException) as e:
            raise custom_exceptions.BinanceClientErrorException(str(e))

    def take_profit_order(self, symbol: str, side: str, quantity: float, price: float, stop_price: float, reduce_only: bool = False) -> dict:
        """
        Method to create a take profit order.
        @param symbol: The trading pair symbol (e.g., 'BTCUSDT').
        @param side: BUY or SELL.
        @param quantity: The quantity to trade.
        @param price: The price at which the order should execute.
        @param stop_price: The price that triggers the take profit order.
        @param reduce_only: If True, order will only reduce the position size.
        @return: Response from Binance API as a dictionary.
        """
        try:
            response = self.client.futures_create_order(
                symbol=symbol,
                side=side,
                quantity=quantity,
                price=price,
                stopPrice=stop_price,
                reduceOnly=reduce_only,
                priceProtect=True,
                type=FUTURE_ORDER_TYPE_TAKE_PROFIT,
                timeInForce=TIME_IN_FORCE_GTC,
                workingType='MARK_PRICE'
            )
            return response
        except (BinanceAPIException, BinanceOrderException) as e:
            raise custom_exceptions.BinanceClientErrorException(str(e))

    def stop_loss_order(self, symbol: str, side: str, quantity: float, stop_price: float, reduce_only: bool = False) -> dict:
        """
        Method to create a stop loss order.
        @param symbol: The trading pair symbol (e.g., 'BTCUSDT').
        @param side: BUY or SELL.
        @param quantity: The quantity to trade.
        @param stop_price: The price that triggers the stop loss order.
        @param reduce_only: If True, order will only reduce the position size.
        @return: Response from Binance API as a dictionary.
        """
        try:
            response = self.client.futures_create_order(
                symbol=symbol,
                side=side,
                quantity=quantity,
                stopPrice=stop_price,
                reduceOnly=reduce_only,
                priceProtect=True,
                type=FUTURE_ORDER_TYPE_STOP_MARKET,
                timeInForce=TIME_IN_FORCE_GTC,
                workingType='MARK_PRICE'
            )
            return response
        except (BinanceAPIException, BinanceOrderException) as e:
            raise custom_exceptions.BinanceClientErrorException(str(e))

    def cancel_all_orders(self, symbol: str) -> dict:
        """
        Method to cancel all open orders for a specific symbol.
        @param symbol: The trading pair symbol (e.g., 'BTCUSDT').
        @return: Response from Binance API as a dictionary.
        """
        try:
            response = self.client.futures_cancel_all_open_orders(symbol=symbol)
            return response
        except (BinanceAPIException, BinanceOrderException) as e:
            raise custom_exceptions.BinanceClientErrorException(str(e))


I use the class like this in the client program:
stop_market_order = self.binance_api.stop_market_order(
            symbol=symbol,
            side=side,
            stop_price=stop_price,
            quantity=quantity,
            reduce_only=False,
        )

        if stop_market_order:
            print("Stop market order created")
            print(stop_market_order)

            stop_loss_order = self.binance_api.stop_loss_order(
                symbol=symbol,
                side="BUY" if "SELL" in side else "SELL",
                quantity=quantity,
                stop_price=tp_price,
                reduce_only=True
            )

            if stop_loss_order:
                print("Stop loss order created")
                print(stop_loss_order)

                take_profit_order = self.binance_api.take_profit_order(
                    symbol=symbol,
                    side=side,
                    quantity=quantity,
                    stop_price=sl_price,
                    price=sl_price,
                    reduce_only=True
                )

                if take_profit_order:
                    print("Take profit order created")
                    print(take_profit_order)
                    return True
                else:
                    return False

            else:
                return False

        else:
            return False

It mostly fails and give different errors which there is no clear documentation on.

Can you check if you have the required permissions for placing the order?
If orders are being placed from backend of your web you may need to add the ip in the binance app or mark the unrestricted ip access to your api keys.
Binance released an update on 26/8/2024. You might check their change logs if that helps.

Yes the IP is added in the Binance web app, thats not the issue here

Manually try to convert some coins to BTC. Then try to create sell limit order at current price of btc. After that the API will work as it is supposed to for any coin. I exactly don't know the exact reason behind this but most of the time when newly created api shows issue. I try this way to solve this.
